# Data not displayed and not filtered in ngTable

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I need to use ngTable to allow filtering by column.
Below my code :

The template :

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td title="'Identifiant'" filter="{ login: 'text'}" sortable="'login'">
                                {{user.login}}</td>
        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The controller :

```
angular.module('tessicommunicationApp')
.controller('UserManagementController', ['$scope', '$filter', 'Principal', 'User', 'ParseLinks', 'Language', 'NgTableParams', function ($scope, $filter, Principal, User, ParseLinks, Language, NgTableParams) {
            //something before...
            $scope.loadAll = function () {
                User.query({
                    page : $scope.page - 1,
                    size : 20
                }, function (result, headers) {
                    $scope.links = ParseLinks.parse(headers('link'));
                    $scope.totalItems = headers('X-Total-Count');
                    //$scope.users becomes an array of ressources
                    $scope.users = result;
                });
            };
            //something again...
            $scope.loadAll();
            //something again...
            $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                    page : 1, // show first page
                    count : 10, // count per page
                    sorting : {
                        name : 'asc' // initial sorting
                    }
                }, {
                    total : 0,
                    getData : function ($defer, params) {
                        var filter = params.filter();
                        var sorting = params.sorting();
                        var count = params.count();
                        var page = params.page();

                        $defer.resolve($scope.users);

                    },
                    data : $scope.users

                })
        }
    ]);
```

There are probably several error, but I already tried many things...tell me the right one please !

Comment: In the brower, when I display the table, nothing is listed.
But when I enter a character in filter field, the whole list is displayed then.
Where as, I loaded ($scope.users affected with loadAll() method) all the content at start in the controller !

Comment: ^ should be incluedd in your question :)

Comment: Does your _User.query_  return the **result** in your **$scope.users** variable?